# scrapy parse or parse_item not being executed after middleware with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I'm using selenium and scrapy to get content of a web page, Selenium it's to bypass Incapsula anti-bot protection and it works fine... If I print the content of the body variable inside the middleware it brings the whole web page

this is the middleware (I'm using two prints for debugging purposes)

```
class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
        print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.headless = True
        self.options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        self.options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        self.options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        self.options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
        self.options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        self.options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
        self.options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
        self.options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=self.options)

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  PROCESS REQUEST")
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = self.driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)s all the HTML
```

this next code is my spider. I'm using prints to check whether the definitions parse_item and parse are being executed, but as you can see in the log, they are not being printed, so I asume those definitions are never being executed

```
class GetWork(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'GetWork'
    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT':5,   #Cantidad de elementos a buscar. Comienza a contar desde el 0.
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':1,   #Cantidad de url que puede visitar a la vez.
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS':1,   #Cantidad de elementos que puede visitar a la vez.
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {'middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 543,}
    }
    allowed_domain = ['www.getwork.com']
    search = 'Software Engineer'.replace(' ','-')
    start_urls = ['https://www.getwork.com/search/results/'+search+'-jobs' ]
    

    file = open("getWork_urls.txt", "a+") 
    file.close()

    url_visitadas = leer_datos("getWork_urls") 

    rules = (

        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny = (url_visitadas), restrict_xpaths = ('//a[contains(@class, "btn-back-next")]'))),

        Rule(LinkExtractor( deny = (url_visitadas), restrict_xpaths = ('//div[contains(@class,"job-listing-clickable")]')), callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
    )
    
    def parse(self, response):
        print("ENTERS PARSE",response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print('ENTERS PARSE_ITEM')
        print(response)
        direccion_url = response.url

        item = JobItem()
        item['url']  = response.url
        try:
            insertar_datos("getWork_urls",direccion_url)
            print("Datos insertados correctamente.")
        except:
            print("No se han insertado.")
        yield item
```

This is the log I'm getting

```
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.8.12 (default, Dec 21 2021, 11:05:26) - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 21.0.
0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Linux-5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 5,
 'CONCURRENT_ITEMS': 1,
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) '
               'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'}
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: e55784b1b14d73bc
2022-01-30 07:06:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://localhost:40119/session {"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog
:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--headless", "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--ignor
e-certificate-errors", "--allow-running-insecure-content", "--disable-extensions", "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--proxy-bypass-list=*", "--start-maximized", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox"]}}},
"desiredCapabilities": {"browserName": "chrome", "pageLoadStrategy": "normal", "goog:chromeOptions": {"extensions": [], "args": ["--headless", "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
 like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36", "--window-size=1920,1080", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--allow-running-insecure-content", "--disable-extensions", "--proxy-server='direct://'", "--proxy-bypass-list=*", "
--start-maximized", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox"]}}}
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:40119
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:40119 "POST /session HTTP/1.1" 200 751
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  PROCESS REQUEST
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://localhost:40119/session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/url {"url": "https://www.getwork.com/search/results/Software-Engineer-jobs"}
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:40119 "POST /session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/url HTTP/1.1" 200 14
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:40119/session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/source {}
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:40119 "GET /session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/source HTTP/1.1" 200 886
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://localhost:40119/session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/url {}
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://localhost:40119 "GET /session/0a37abc946164331915d803e08833fef/url HTTP/1.1" 200 73
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2022-01-30 07:06:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.getwork.com/search/results/Software-Engineer-jobs> (referer: None)
2022-01-30 07:06:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-01-30 07:06:42 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/response_bytes': 799,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.756408,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 30, 7, 6, 42, 8004),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 14,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 56594432,
 'memusage/startup': 56594432,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 30, 7, 6, 41, 251596)}
2022-01-30 07:06:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
root@072c20105b64:/scrapy_v2.1#
```

Comment: You didn't add `url_visitadas` to your code, so I removed it from the rules and the spider works for me. I'm getting output from `parse` and `parse_item`.

Comment: @SuperUser `url_visitadas` is just an empty txt that should have urls only, but even when it's empty the output is the same. I even removed it from the rules and the output (that I show in the question) keeps the same. Could it be another problem in my side ?

Comment: Now it's not working for me also so I took a look. It's not bypassing incapsula, you can't print `body` in the middleware and see. (BTW in crawlSpider you shouldn't overwrite parse function).

Comment: @SuperUser So that means incapsula is detecting Selenium and blocking it... But how is that possible ? isn't it supposed that Selenium has the same behaviour (with headers and other things) as a human browsing when is making a request ? how am I supposed to bypass Incapsula then ? I thought selenium was the solution
(thanks for the comment about parse function, I'll change that)

Comment: I don't think you need selenium for this particular website. Just plain `scrapy` and some `USER_AGENT` will work just fine. Also as long as you are not being too aggressive with your scraping, you should not get blocked.

Comment: @msenior_ I'm not sure if I'm not using the `USER_AGENT` right, but if you see my code, before using selenium I tried scraping the web page using a user agent but it didn't work. Actually you can see my line in the code `USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',`